# how to fix wordpress troubleshooting error?

Tags: wordpress, error, administration, wordpress.com

so 15 minutes ago im editing my own website in wordpress using elementor and adding an image to my website without linking any url there (just plain image) thn suddenly after im not touching anything for 15 min ( im having lunch) suddenly its show error on my website page also i cant open my wordpress admin since the error showing there too..... can anyone help me how to fix it? i dont want to lose my website

There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress.[image: error page]

Comment: I've voted to close this as off-topic here - hopefully it will be migrated to wordpress.stackexchange.com - which is where this question belongs.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is **about WordPress development**. This *may* be a better fit at the [WordPress Development](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange website. Be sure to read their [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) before posting to make sure your question meets their requirements

Answer (score 1):

You should have received an email with a special link to the dashboard that will allow you in despite the error.

Once in there, disable all plugins and themes and enable them again one at a time.

Eventually you will trigger whatever caused the problem.

Comment: am i gonna lose all the edit and more importantly my website?

Comment: Unlikely.  Your changes are saved in the database.  Doing what I described doesn't impact the database

Comment: If you are worried about losing your website (and if so, why don't you have scheduled backups), back up all the files in your web directory [ usually public_html or similar] and do a dump of the database.

Comment: Also, if you want to disable all your plugins to get to the site (ie you don't get the emailed message, create a new directory under wp-content - for example called plugins.deleted, and move everything from wp-content/plugins to wp-content/plugins-deleted which will stop the plugins loaded.   You can then move them back one by one, testing the site between activating plugins - and work out which plugin is causing the issue.)